# Can't connect to computer via SBS2011 RWA

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-sbs-2011, windows

I've got an SBS 2011 Essentials server. Users a able to log on to Remote Web Access using their username and password.

However, the trouble starts when a users attempts to log on remotely to his/her computer from the Remote Web Access website.

When the user clicks on his/her computer (in the RWA website), the user is first presented with a window listing Publisher, Type, Remote Computer name and Gateway Server. Everything seems fine here, and the user clicks Connect. The user credentials are provided, and a connection is attempted.

However, the logon attempt always fails with the message "The logon attempt failed".

The logon attempt always generates three log events in the server log:

```
EventId: 4672 - Special Logon
EventId: 4624 - Logon
EventId: 4634 - Logoff
```

All events happens have the same timestamp.

No events are logged on the client machine which the user attempts to log on to.

Others have solved this by going to their IIS server and enable "Windows Authentication" for Rpc and RpcWithCert (in Default Web Site). However, this is in place on the server.

I've also got RD CAPs and RD RAPs in place.

As a side note; if i try to connect to any of the machines using the Remote Desktop Connection using the "Connect from anywhere" functionality - then things work flawlessly! In other words, the error only occurs when attempting to login to a computer via the Remote Web Access website.

I've run out of ideas for how I can solve this (too many hours spent). Any ideas highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Make the following change in the Exchange Management Shell:

Get-OutlookAnywhere | Set-OutlookAnywhere –IISAuthenticationMethods: Basic, ntlm

The Autoconfig service will update IIS for you, and both Basic and Windows authentication will be added properly.